# react-native add '...' on the right of card to show more information

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add the 3 littles dots on the right of a card to show more information on click but cannot find how this is called.

On android it is called ""overflow menu" but the only component using `overflow` I found is "toolbarAndroid". I cannot use it because i work on Android & IOS.

Did you know how to do this ?
Actually i'm using "react-native-elements" for the card but they don't provide this option. 
Maybe i have to create a component for that

[image: what i want to reproduce on IOS & Android]

My actual code, not using "title" props of card because i don't want to display the divider line.

```
  renderProject(project) {
    const { id, name, description, species, images } = project;
    return (
      <Card containerStyle={thisstyles.cardContainerStyle} key={id}>
        <View>
          <Text style={thisstyles.projectName}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginLeft:15}}>
          <Text style={{color:'mediumvioletred'}}>{description}</Text>
          <Text>
            {species} Espèces {images} Images
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think you can add transparent image with proper design

Comment: to which component ? react-native-element card don't have icon on the title

Comment: You haven't added code so not sure but on the line where your cards title / first line is rendered

Comment: Add image after this line: `<Text style={thisstyles.projectName}>{name}</Text>`

Comment: yes my bad. the "title" props of card component take only a string. i will create a custom component for this

Comment: but this "3 dots" are used by facebook on IOS & android button. so they should put this functionnality in react-native. how they name it, i didn't found yet

Answer (score 1):

As you have used custom component just add Image to show triple dots.

```
<View>
  <Text style={thisstyles.projectName}>{name}</Text>
  <Image style={position: 'absolute', right: 0}
      source={require('../../path/to/image')} />
</View>
```

In your given module [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/card/),

```
<Card
  title='HELLO WORLD'
  image={require('../images/pic2.jpg')}> // you can play around with this
```

Comment: the image will not be clickable , so cannot be used for such action. I'm creating my custom component  with title & callback props

Comment: you need to add `TouchableOpacity` on image

Answer (score 1):

You can Crate Your component Like this without any image

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Text,Header,CardItem} from 'native-base';

class CardExample extends Component{

  _renderSearchResult(){
    return(
      <View>
        <CardItem style={styles.cardView}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.locationRowContainer}>
              <View style={styles.addressContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.locationText}>
                  My current location
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{alert('You cliked me')}}>
              <View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

          </View>
        </CardItem>

        <CardItem style={styles.cardView}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.locationRowContainer}>
              <View style={styles.addressContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.locationText}>
                  My current location
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{alert('You cliked me')}}>
              <View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.circleDot}>
              </View>
              </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

          </View>
        </CardItem>
      </View>
    )
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>

        {this._renderSearchResult()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles={
  container:{
    flex:1,
  },
  cardView:{
    elevation:5,
    marginTop:8,
  },
  locationRowContainer:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    marginTop:21,

  },
  addressContainer:{
    flex:3,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'flex-start'
  },
  locationText:{

    fontSize:16,
    color:'black'
  },
  circleDot:{
    backgroundColor:'black',
    height:6,
    width:6,
    borderRadius:6/2,
    marginBottom:2,
  },
  mapLocationContainer:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'flex-end'
  }
}
export default CardExample;
```